# How do I get the tokens causing errors in bison?

Tags: bison

For example:

```
rule:
    TOK_OP TOK_WORD { some action; }
    | TOK_OP error TOK_WORD { some action2; }
;
```

If there is a input string `TOK_OP something else TOK_WORD`, I want to get the "something else", but how can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://oreilly.com/linux/excerpts/9780596155971/error-reporting-recovery.html

This site saved a me a lot of trouble when trying to determine exactly what was causing my errors, whether it be telling me which token specifically caused the problem or was able to look at the entire line. Hope this helps!